# RXSwift + UITableView with animated Cell ends up in flashing reloads

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I have the following issue. I use RxSwift to bind my datasource to an UITableView like this:

```
self.presenter.posts
      .bind(to: self.tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "ListPostsCell")) { index, model, cell in
        if let cell = cell as? ImagePostTableViewCell {
          cell.viewModel = model
          cell.actionButton.rx.action = self.action(for: model.postId, index: index)
        }
      }.disposed(by: self.bag)
```

When the tableview reaches the end of the datasource count I request more data and update the datasource (infinite scroll) like this:

```
self.tableView.rx.willDisplayCell
      .map { $0.indexPath.item }
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .withLatestFrom(self.presenter.posts) { (item, posts) -> Bool in
        return item == posts.count - 3
      }
      .filter { $0 }
      .withLatestFrom(self.presenter.posts)
      .map { UsersPosts.Request(after: $0.last?.postId) }
      .bind(to: self.usersPostsInteractor.receiveUsersPosts.inputs)
      .disposed(by: self.bag)
```

This works fine and I can scroll infinite as expected. The problem is within my Cell:

```
class ImagePostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  @IBOutlet weak var postImageView: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var haiScoreLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var lastVoteLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var actionButton: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var activtiyIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

  var bag: DisposeBag?

  var viewModel: ImagePostTableViewCellViewModel? {
    didSet {
      let bag = DisposeBag()

      guard let vm = viewModel else { return }

      vm.image.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: UIImage())
        .drive(onNext: { image in
          self.updateAppearanceFor(image)
        }).disposed(by: bag)

      self.haiScoreLabel.text = vm.haiScoreText
      self.lastVoteLabel.text = vm.lastVoteText
      self.actionButton.setTitle(vm.actionLabelText, for: .normal)
      self.activtiyIndicator.startAnimating()
      self.bag = bag
    }
  }

  func updateAppearanceFor(_ image: UIImage?, animated: Bool = true) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      if animated {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
          self.displayImage(image)
        }
      } else {
        self.displayImage(image)
      }
    }
  }

  private func displayImage(_ image: UIImage?) {
    if let image = image {
      self.show(image: image)
    } else {
      self.hide()
    }
  }

  private func show(image: UIImage) {
    self.postImageView.image = image
    self.postImageView.alpha = 1.0
    self.haiScoreLabel.alpha = 1.0
    self.lastVoteLabel.alpha = 1.0
    self.activtiyIndicator.stopAnimating()
  }

  private func hide() {
    self.postImageView.image = nil
    self.postImageView.alpha = 0
    self.haiScoreLabel.alpha = 0
    self.lastVoteLabel.alpha = 0
    self.activtiyIndicator.startAnimating()
  }

  override public func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.displayImage(.none)
    self.viewModel = nil
    self.bag = nil
  }
}
```

As you can see there is an animation which ends up in an super smooth scrolling behaviour - but because of the datasource update, with every reload the animation starts and unchanged content flashes because of the animation.

In the end I want to avoid the reload for the visible cell but I really desperate here.

Any hints to follow? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Maybe this will help here: https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources. There is an animated data source that does not reload the entire table.

Comment: RxDataSource just solved it... I wanted to avoid the usage - thought it will be overhead but it is exactly what I needed. Thanks for the helpful hint!